# How can I solve this Jiffy constructor error?

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, flutter-dependencies, jiffy

I am not sure the best constructor to add in this use case.
Still trying to figure out flutter so I got stuck here while trying to build an app.

I have tried the different constructors like "jiffy.datetime" "jiffy.parsejiffy" etc but they seem not to have solved the issue but keeps returning the same error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRgBN.png)

Please help

Comment: if you take your mouse on the red lines, you will see what errors are happening. try reading that or share those errors with code.

Comment: Thank you Jay.
This is the message attached.


"The class 'Jiffy' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'Jiffy'.dartnew_with_undefined_constructor_default"

Comment: check out this link for more info about constructors https://dart.dev/language/constructors#named-constructors

Answer (score 0):

Based from you code, you seem to use Jiffy incorrectly. As of version `6.0.0` Jiffy does not allow to create its instance soley by calling the constructor

You have to use factory methods to create one

So below I have re-written your code to solve the issue you are having

```dart
// This looks great 
Jiffy createAt = Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(widget.datetime);

// On line 277
// Rather than
final now = Datetime.now() // remove this
// Use Jiffy
final now = Jiffy.now() // Now you have a Jiffy instance

// If you want to get a Datetime from a Jiffy, just write
now.datetime; // This will return a Datetime object/instance


// On line 279
// Rather than creating another instance of Jiffy
Jiffy.parseFromJiffy(createAt).isSame(now, Units.day) // remove this
// Use the createdAt since it a Jiffy instance itself
createdAt.isSame(now, Units.day) // replace it with this

// And one additional thing, the `isSame` methods takes in a Jiffy 
// object/instance, not a Datetime object


// On line 281 - 282
// Rather than
Jiffy(createdAt).isSame(now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1), Units.day))
// Replace it with
createdAt.isSame(now.subtract(days: 1), Units.day))


// On line 284 - 286
// Rather than
Jiffy(createAt).isAfter(now.subtract(const Duration(days: 7), Units.day))
// Replace it with
createdAt.isAfter(now.subtract(days: 7), Units.day))
// or you can use `week: 1` also that Jiffy supports
createdAt.isAfter(now.subtract(weeks: 1), Units.day))


// On line 290 - 291
// Rather than 
Jiffy(createdAt).isAfter(Jiffy(now).subtract(years: 1), Units.day))
// Replace it with
createdAt.isAfter(now.subtract(years: 1), Units.day))
```

Hope this helps on how to use Jiffy, if you have additional questions, please feel free to ask